# Why is a $scope variable have a value in one function but defined in another function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

the `isCheckedIn` function is being called when the view is initialized and the checkin function is being called when a button is clicked.

I'm not sure why but the $scope.users_events is undefined in `isCheckedIn` but has a value in `checkIn`

What am I doing wrong?

These are the two functions

```
$scope.isCheckedIn = function() {
  console.log($scope.users_events);
  //more code
}

$scope.checkIn = function() {
  console.log($scope.users_events);
  //more code
}
```

This is the function where the variable is coming from

```
function getCheckedInUsers(){
  dataService.getCollectionForId('events', id, 'users')
  .then(function(response) {
        $scope.users = response.data.relatedObjects.users;
        $scope.users_events = response.data.data;
    });
}

getCheckedInUsers();
```

Comment: The response didn't come yet. http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: Oh okay. How can I fix it?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. This is the expected behavior for functions declared on initialize, AJAX requests won't be resolved yet. If you want to use data as soon as response comes you should do it inside .then(function). Another way is to add a $watcher in the controller and $apply inside the promise function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the `isCheckedIn` function is being called when the view is initialized and the `checkIn` function is being called when a button is clicked.

`dataService.getCollectionForId('events', id, 'users')` is going to return a `Promise`.  The first function passed into `then` will be executed after the `Promise` resolves successfully.

This execution probably happens after the view has initialized, which is why `checkedIn` works but `isCheckedIn` doesn't.

To "fix" this you could make sure you re-evaluate computed expressions after retrieving data (instead of relying on the digest cycle), or more generally, any time any of the inputs have changed.  I'm assuming `isCheckedIn` is doing other useful initialization, in which case maybe it should be called inside the `then` function at the end.

Normally you would just use a directive or view binding like `{{ $scopeExpression }}` to display a value on the `$scope` that will stay up to date as it changes... If that expression is expensive in time to compute (or needs to make a call to a service) then you need to do something else to keep the digest cycle quick and application responsive.

For example, here's a general solution to the general problem - if you had a set of computations that needed to be recomputed from a variety of input sources anytime any (1) of the inputs changed, assuming the inputs were relatively small (like numbers or short strings) and not arrays (you just have to be careful about how you define "equality") and you could do this with just (1) watch:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return {
       input1: expression1,
       input2: expression2,
       // ... 
    }
}, function (value) {
   // This function will only execute if at least one of the inputs changed 

   var computations = [];
   computations.push(computationA(value.input1, value.input2 /* ,.. */));
   computations.push(computationB(value.input1, value.input2 /* ,.. */));
   computations.push(computationC(value.input1, value.input2 /* ,.. */));
   // ...

   $q.all(promises).then(function (computations) {
      $scope.computationAResult = computations[0];
      $scope.computationBResult = computations[1];
      $scope.computationCResult = computations[2];

      // Do synchronous work here on inputs so that all $scope variables get updated at once.
   });

}, true /* Deep watch */);
```

This way you don't do lots of expensive computations on each digest cycle.